# Why does is_invocable work differently with reference parameters?

Tags: c++

It seems to work differently only for this one case. What is going on here?

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo_value(int i){}
void foo_ref(int& i){}
void foo_cref(const int& i){}

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_value), int>::value);
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_ref), int>::value); // what's wrong with this?
    static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_cref), int>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_value), int&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_ref), int&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(foo_cref), int&>::value);
}
```

Comment: just `int` is an r-value, when the function takes an l-valie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is_invocable` and similar type traits allow you to specify not only the types of the arguments, but also their value categories. If `T` is some non-reference, non-void type, then for the purposes of `is_invocable`:

- `T` means "rvalue of type `T`".
- `T&` means "lvalue of type `T`".

Since `foo_ref` cannot be called with an *rvalue* of type `int`, the result of `is_invocable` is false when `int` is specified as the second argument.

*Edit:* This behaviour is specified in terms of `std::declval`. The expression `std::declval<U>()`, which is only allowed to appear inside an unevaluated expression, has return type `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<U>`, and according to the reference-collapsing rules, this means it is an lvalue if `U` is an lvalue reference type, and is otherwise an rvalue. The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) for `std::is_invocable` mentions that both `Fn` and `ArgTypes...` are subject to this `declval` treatment, which means you also have the opportunity to specify whether the function-like entity is an lvalue or rvalue. If you want to know whether some other type trait also does this, look for which types, if any, appear in `declval` expressions.

Answer (score 4):

It says that its not invocable that way... because it's indeed not invocable.

Try calling `foo_ref` with a int prvalue:

```
foo_ref(int{}); // does not compile
```

You'll see that this code is failing to compile, because a prvalue cannot be bound to a non const lvalue reference.

Comment: With `template <class Fn, class ... ArgTypes> struct is_invocable`, could you add an explanation why in `is_invocable<someFunction, int>`, the second parameter `int` is an rvalue reference? I don't get it.

Comment: @lubgr the second parameter `int` is not an rvalue reference as far as I know. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I am the one who is missing something I think :) My question is: why does `is_incovable<someFunction, int>` gives the result for an rvalue reference. It's invocable for an lvalue reference, but I can't see how the `int` template parameter distinguishes between these two options.

Comment: @lubgr okay, so here's a very simplistic example on what `is_invocable` is doing for this case. It checks the validity of this expression `function(std::declval<Arg>())`. But for a `declval` that works for all type, it must return an rvalue reference for every rvalue types, including prvalues and xvalues. The result is that declval returns a lvalue or an xvalue.

Comment: @lubgr this is because forwarding will cause prvalues to become xvalues anyways so it's in a way, more accurate.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.