# How to write a type trait that checks if tuple types are compatible with function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I am trying to write a type trait that checks whether the types stored in a tuple are compatible with the arguments of a given callable.

Currently, I have 'almost working' code, shown below. However, static assert fails in the last statement with a callable that expects reference parameters (e.g. `[](int&, std::string&){}`), I don't really understand why it's failing. And how does one write a trait that is inclusive for this type as well?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template<typename, typename>
struct is_callable_with_tuple: std::false_type {};

template<typename Func, template<typename...> class Tuple, typename... Args>
struct is_callable_with_tuple<Func, Tuple<Args...>>: std::is_invocable<Func, Args...> {};

template<typename Func, typename Args>
constexpr bool is_callable_with_tuple_v = is_callable_with_tuple<Func, Args>::value;

int main() {    
    static_assert(is_callable_with_tuple_v<decltype([](int, std::string){}), std::tuple<int, std::string>>); // OK
    static_assert(is_callable_with_tuple_v<decltype([](const int&, const std::string&){}), std::tuple<int, std::string>>); // OK
    static_assert(is_callable_with_tuple_v<decltype([](int&, std::string&){}), std::tuple<int, std::string>>); // Fails
}
```

Comment: Just found out a tuple with stored references fixes the assert: `    static_assert(is_callable_with_tuple_v<decltype([](int&, std::string&){}), std::tuple<int&, std::string&>>);`, but it's not completely what I want

Comment: The tuple is a red herring. `std::is_invocable_v<void(int&), int>` is `false` because it makes no sense to define it any other way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883044/why-does-is-invocable-work-differently-with-reference-parameters

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this trait? The code is actually correct, `decltype([](int&, std::string&){})` cannot be called with `int, std::string` because this would require to bind rvalues to non-const lvalue reference which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to modify your trait slightly:

```
template<typename Func, 
         template<typename...> class Tuple, 
         typename... Args>
struct is_callable_with_tuple<Func, Tuple<Args...>>: 
    std::is_invocable<Func, Args&...> {}; // <--- note &
```

Or not, depending on how exactly you plan to use it. If your tuple is always an lvalue, it is probably OK. If not, then you may want to specialise it for an lvalue-reference tuple type:

```
template<typename Func, 
         template<typename...> class Tuple, 
         typename... Args>
struct is_callable_with_tuple<Func, Tuple<Args...>&>:  // <--- note & here
    std::is_invocable<Func, Args&...> {}; // <--- and also here

template<typename Func, 
         template<typename...> class Tuple, 
         typename... Args>
struct is_callable_with_tuple<Func, Tuple<Args...>>:  // <--- note NO & here
    std::is_invocable<Func, Args...> {}; // <--- and also here
```

and use it like this:

```
is_callable_with_tuple<decltype(myfunc), decltype((mytuple))> // note double parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. However I don't completely understand why the double parentheses are necessary in the second solution. Can you explain why? Edit: Ah, googled a bit, as far as I understand (tuple) is an lvalue expression, which will makes it call the first trait .